# SQL Query return values in a set sequence

Tags: sql

I have been trying for a while now to return data from the database with the ID(int) values in the following order.

3, 6, 1, 9, 2, 5.

Is there anyway this can be done?

EDIT: Ok i made a bit of a stuff up in my post. the ID's above are just an example.

I am trying to do this dynamically, based around how many records from another table are linked to the record i want to pull out, e.g. i host 3 branches and each branch has a group of shops how would i determine which has the most?

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should order them in your application. That is an arbitrary sequence...

Comment: As you see below, yes you can.  The question should be Should I do this? and the answer would be an emphatic NO.  The solution to what you are trying to do is very brittle.

Comment: Ok guys thank you for the advise though none of them solved my problem they did however point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, something like this:

```
select ID from tablename
order by
  CASE WHEN ID = 3 THEN 1
       WHEN ID = 6 THEN 2
       WHEN ID = 1 THEN 3
       WHEN ID = 9 THEN 4
       WHEN ID = 2 THEN 5
       WHEN ID = 5 THEN 6
       ELSE 7 END, ID ASC
```

This will put 3,6,1,9,2,5 and afterwords the other numbers in ascending order.

Answer (score 2):

```
select cols from table where
order by 
   case ID when 3 then 0 
   when 6 then 1 
   when 1 then 2
   when 9 then 3 
   ...
   end
```

You get the idea...

Answer (score 1):

Create a table for the sorting.

CREATE TABLE SortPriority (
    SourceID int NULL,
    Priority int NULL)

Populate it with the ids and what order they should showup in.  Join to the table.  and use SortPriority.Priority in your sorting.

You can more easily change the sorting around this way.  You would just need to modify the data.  You can also later write scripts to populate the table to handle predictable needs in the changing of the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

A split function like this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSplit(@str varchar(max), @dlm char(1))
RETURNS @result TABLE (id int, value varchar(50))
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE
    @id int, @value varchar(50),
    @lastpos int, @pos int, @len int;
  SET @id = 0;
  SET @len = LEN(@str);
  SET @lastpos = 1;
  SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@dlm, @str + @dlm);
  IF @pos <> 0
    WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
      SET @value = SUBSTRING(@str, @lastpos, @pos - @lastpos);
      IF @value <> '' BEGIN
        SET @id = @id + 1;
        INSERT INTO @result VALUES (@id, @value);
      END;
      IF @pos > @len BREAK;
      SET @lastpos = @pos + 1;
      SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@dlm, @str + @dlm, @lastpos);
    END;
  RETURN;
END
```

would return a row set containing not only the values, but also their indexes within the list. You could then use the function in this way:

```
SELECT
…
FROM atable t
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Split('3,6,1,9,2,5', ',') s ON t.Value = s.Value
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN s.id IS NULL THEN 2147483647 ELSE s.id END
```