# Sql server order by value not by field name

Tags: sql, sql-server

suppose my table structure is like

```
ID       OEReference
---      ------------
1         00000634B9
2         00000634B6
3         0005000053
4         0002855071
5         0000940148
6         0001414825
7         00000634B9
```

i want that they way i supply OEReference that order should maintain in output.
my sql is like

```
Select * from mytable where OEReference in ('00000634B9','0001414825','00000634B6')
```

the above statement did not return resultset according to the order of **IN** clause. i know that it is not possible by **ORDER BY CLAUSE**

how can i do it with simple sql statement in sql server. thanks

Comment: You could use an approach like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8739026).

Comment: @and: He's not sorting in ascending order of `OEReference`

Comment: @Andomar: No, he isn't. Nor does my answer suggest doing so. The idea is to pass the value list as a single CSV string, split it with a split function and sort the final result set on the index column returned by the function.

Comment: @AndriyM: Aha, my mistake, I assumed the split function returned only a single column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a temporary table as a filter.  An`inner join` will enforce the filter, and you can sort on the identity column:

```
declare @filter table (id int identity, ref varchar(50))
insert @filter values ('00000634B9')
insert @filter values ('0001414825')
insert @filter values ('00000634B6')

select  *
from    YourTable yt
join    @filter filter
on      filter.ref = yt.OEReference
order by
        filter.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please here is my solution for you:

```
SELECT [id], [OEReference]      

  FROM [Tbl]

  where [OEReference] in ('002', '001')

  order by case [OEReference]
      when '002' then 1
      when '001' then 2
      end
```

Please note: this can decrease performance of your server. It depends on how many rows in table you have. However, you can easily add index for OEReference. Off course, you should generate such query **dynamically**.
My solution is not close ideal. Maybe you found it useful for you.

Happy coding!

Comment: This would work but it duplicates the `in` clause, kind of error prone